# New-PSSession is not returning a session to import and use

Tags: javascript, c#, powershell

I'm probably doing this the wrong way and should use WSManConnectionInfo instead somehow but a lot of examples I've found point to this method of creating a new PowerShell Session in a C# app under different credentials as valid method.

I'm stuck with the piece that invokes the New-PSSession as it does not return a session object (returns an empty collection) that I can use in the next set of commands. My goal is to create a C# function that takes in a PowerShell script block and runs it with admin credentials.

(*UPDATE*) The code below now works. Be sure to check "Enable-WSManCredSSP" params for the client machine name or it will fail to delegate credentials when creating a new PSSession. I changed the code to use the local machine name for the client versus * for all on the domain, I believe using * is a bad security practice.

```
    public static IEnumerable<PSObject> RunScriptBlock(string block)
    {
        var nc = Domains.Default.GetNetworkCredential();
        var creds = new PSCredential(nc.Domain + "\\" + nc.UserName, nc.SecurePassword);
        using (Runspace rs = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {

            rs.Open();
            using (var psh = PowerShell.Create())
            {
                psh.Runspace = rs;
                PSSession session = null;
                try
                {
                    psh.AddCommand("Enable-WSManCredSSP");
                    psh.AddParameter("Role", "Client");
                    psh.AddParameter("DelegateComputer", Environment.MachineName + ".mydomain.com");
                    psh.AddParameter("Force", true);
                    psh.Invoke();
                    psh.Commands.Clear();
                    psh.AddCommand("Enable-WSManCredSSP");
                    psh.AddParameter("Role", "Server");
                    psh.AddParameter("Force", true);
                    psh.Invoke();
                    psh.Commands.Clear();
                    psh.AddCommand("New-PSSession");
                    psh.AddParameter("Credential", creds);
                    psh.AddParameter("Authentication", "Credssp");
                    session = psh.Invoke()[0].BaseObject as PSSession;
                    psh.Commands.Clear();
                    psh.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("", "");
                    psh.AddCommand("Invoke-Command");
                    psh.AddParameter("Session", session);
                    ScriptBlock sb = new RunspaceInvoke().Invoke("{ " + block + " }")[0].BaseObject as ScriptBlock;
                    psh.AddParameter("ScriptBlock", sb);
                    var results = psh.Invoke();
                    //if (results.HasErrors)
                    //{

                    //}
                    return results;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return null;
                }
                finally
                {
                    psh.Commands.Clear();
                    psh.AddCommand("Remove-PSSession");
                    psh.AddParameter("Session", session);
                    psh.Invoke();
                    rs.Close();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Then what *does* it return? An empty collection? A collection with something else?

Comment: Yes, it returns an empty collection. If I add in $env:username, it will return my current id

Comment: The only case in which `New-PSSession` doesn't emit a `PSSession` object is when it fails. Check `psh.HadErrors` and `psh.Streams.Error`

Comment: Mathias, you're the man. There was an error and it was due to the Enable-WSManCredSSP cmd not being set to the correct client. I changed it so that it would not enable for all machines in the domain. I'll post an update.